# How to convert numbers to hexadecimal value in AngularJS. And the numbers will be taken from user.

Tags: html, angularjs

i tried this

```
//Body
<input type="number" ng-model="show">
<h2>{{show}}</h2>
 //Controlelr
a.controller("cont", function($scope, convertr){
$scope.show = convertr.myFunc(show);
});
//Custom Service
a.service("convertr", function(){
this.myFunc = function(){
return x.toString(16)
};
});
```

Sorry I am new in angularjs and i am new in Stackoverflow. So dont know much about how to do things. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Try with `(number + 0x00000).toString(16)` instead ...

Comment: @davidkonrad no need to append 0x* `(number).toString(16)` - will work also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a service as a `factory`, and this factory must *return* whatever you need to expose from that service :

```
a.factory("convertr", function() {
  return {
    myFunc: function(x) {
      return x.toString(16)
    }
  }
});
```

You van have local variable and functions in the service

```
a.factory("convertr", function() {

  var localVariable = 42;

  function doSomething() {
  }

  return {
    myFunc: function(x) {
      return x.toString(16)
    }
  }
});
```

You can inject other services by adding the service names as parameter to the service function `a.factory("convertr", function($http) {` (implicit, not recommended) or preferred with inline array annotation

```
a.factory("convertr", ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    myFunc: function(x) {
      return x.toString(16)
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I am new in angularjs. Can you please suggest me a good site for tutorials?

Comment: You could see this -> https://blog.revillweb.com/angularjs-tutorial-learn-angularjs-in-30-minutes-35b5eae52dc2 It seem to be straight on, even though it is old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple scope-wrapping to call `toString` of `number`

```js
function hexSample() {
    let number = prompt("enter your number", "");
    if (number != null) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        "Heximal number of " + number + " : " + (Number(number)).toString(16);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hexSample()">Try it</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I was trying to do it with angularjs. But Thanks bro :)